# Changing origin in SingleViewPort layout Eyeshot control in .net windows application?

Tags: .net, graphics, eyeshot

How to change default origin in SingleViewPort layout Eyeshot control in .net windows application? Eyeshot is a graphics tool.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more why you want to change the origin position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this library for a couple of week now and I don't think there is a way to change this. In fact, the origin **is** the origin (0, 0, 0), you can't change that and I don't understand why you would want to do that...

If your goal is to rotate or do some transformation in relation to another point than the origin, there is always a way. Most of the function can take a Point3D in their parameters to make this possible. Also, you can translate your object so it react to the real origin (0,0,0).

If it's just to make it disapear, you can call

```
singleViewportLayout1.OriginSymbol.Visible = false;
```

That's all I can think about for now. If you add more information in your original post or as a comment, I could edit my post to help you more.